# use Stata variable labels in results

Tags: stata

I have several numeric variables `var_1-var_5` with variable labels attached, like "Rain" and "Snow".

Can any mainstream commands use my variable labels when printing to the results window?

For example, it would be really nice if `summarize` did so. So far, the labels seem to be useful only for graphics and the `describe` command.

Comment: I think you mean `summarize`, not `summary`.

Comment: Ah, you are right. I've just been typing `summ` :)

Comment: `su` works and flags the experienced user!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the answer is: if the command can do it, then it will be documented or done by default.

From http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2011-09/msg00902.html (2011), I quote Nick Cox:

> ... if a command has no option to show variable labels, then you can't
>   show variable labels with that command; it is usually the case that
>   there is no such option with statistical commands, because typically
>   there wouldn't be enough space to show variable labels; and if there
>   is such an option, then it will be documented. The only alternative is
>   that you learn how to program in Stata and write your own alternative
>   commands.

Some user-written commands that maybe do what you want (with respect to `summarize`) are:

```
ssc describe labsumm
```

and

```
ssc describe fsum
```

These are from http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2008-07/msg00850.html.

Comment: Ah, those packages are good finds. Thank you for those and the relevant quote. After posting, I realized that `univar` also has the option. This is not a very satisfying resolution, but I guess that's an unfortunate consequence of how Stata's documentation is structured. I find it very strange that `search "variable label", all` yields zero results, even though I see that exact phrase in the `help univar` doc.

Comment: I use `search` and the manuals, but many times I also complement with my own web searches (Google), paying special attention to Statalist and www.ats.ucla.edu links. For example, a Google search with `stata + variable labels and summarize` contains within its first page, all information in my answer (and more, including a refrence to `univar`). Reading **[U] 4.8.1** How search works, and by results given in practice, I conclude that `search` doesn't exhaustively look through the help files of (un)installed user-written commands. Instead, it searches in titles and description sections.

Comment: Running `ssc describe univar`, one can see that "variable label" is nowhere to be found. So that wouldn't come up in the search. An arbitrary search like `search displays` would have `univar` in its results because "displays" can be found in `univar`'s description. That's what I can reason, for now.

Comment: No; `search` starts by looking in Stata's own `.key` files. On the question, the key detail is mundane: If you want to display variable labels, where will you find the space?

Comment: @Nick, what are you negating exactly? I understand that `search` will start with its own database (the .key files), but will also check user-written programs in the Internet (as stated in **[U] 4.9**). I've tried this again, and behaviour is consistent with my previous statement: I have tried `search pvar`, and the user-written command `centroid` comes up, presumably, because in the description as per `ssc describe centroid`, the word grou**pvar** is present. As known, `search` by default, actually does `search, all`.

Comment: @NickCox: My labels aren't very long, about the same length as the variable names. So they could fit anywhere the variable names normally go in the results window. The "Rain" and "Snow" from my example are literally what I'm using. :)

Comment: @RobertoFerrer Thanks for looking into it. Browsing in Windows Explorer, I have found the pdf docs. If I could find a folder containing the hlp files (and maybe key files, which I hadn't heard of before), I could do a full text search with another tool (Windows search or notepad++). Do you know where those are? I'm sure a local copy is kept for packages I have already installed at least...

Comment: Sure, but a command designed for generality has to truncate variable labels in many instances. Naturally I agree with you that it's often desirable to show variable labels. There could be rules or habits that you can show variable labels but only the first # characters; I think some programs do that. In many of my own programs, I allow variable labels to be shown optionally instead of variable names; it's then the user's choice and their responsibility to shorten variable labels if they want them to fit or to use moderate space.

Comment: Ah ok, I've found that docs for installed packages are in `sysdir`'s `PLUS` (`c:\ado\personal\ ` on my system), while the base packages are in a `BASE` subfolder (`\_`). This provides me with a clumsy workaround, at least for packages I already have.

Comment: `viewsource summarize.sthlp` shows, for example, the source for this help file, including directory. But it is decorated with SMCL so maybe that will affect your search strategy. See `help smcl` if in doubt. I would only do this if I **really** knew what I was doing; I mean, handling installation files with software other than Stata itself.

Comment: @Roberto Ferrer I am asserting that `search` does not search help files. But see `hsearch`.

Comment: @NickCox Thanks, `hsearch` is much better way of doing what I was attempting. I hope it continues to be available (as I see it is no longer officially supported).

Comment: I have not heard discussions of that on Statalist or at users' meetings.